# Terraform for providing dependent jar path in AWS Glue

Tags: terraform, aws-glue

I am trying to deploy an AWS Glue job through terraform. However, having gone through the documentation over the below, I am unable to find a way to configure "Dependent jars path" in Terraform as I am referencing a jar file in my AWS Glue code
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/glue_job

Is there a way to get around this please?
[Click here for a screen grab of the Dependent jars path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ihuB.png)

Comment: That sounds like something that should go into `default_arguments`.  I've worked with Terraform plenty, but not with AWS Glue. Do you have a reference for this "dependent jars path" ? Is that just the Java `CLASSPATH`?

Comment: This would be a path to a jar file located in an AWS S3 bucket

Comment: Are you referring to `--extra-jars`? See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-arguments.html  If so, that would go into the `default_arguments`, as per https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/glue_job

Comment: Thanks Aleksey. I have tried the default arguments. Unfortunately, the "--extra-jars" gets updated as a parameter in the Glue job. This is not what I wanted. I am looking at modifying my AWS Glue as Terraform cannot handle this unfortunately

Comment: Got it, thanks, Prabhu.

Comment: Apologise Aleksey. I actually tried the "--extra-jars" again via Terraform and I got what I expected. Not sure how how/what I'd missed earlier. Thanks again.

Comment: Great @Prabhu and well done for getting it working.  I've re-posted my comments as an answer to help anyone following in your footsteps.  :)  You can accept the answer by selecting the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the `--extra-jars` path (as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-arguments.html) into the `default_arguments`, as per https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/glue_job